# How do I get a variable inside of an "if" statement to be a global variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Python, and I need to get the new DataFrame with the appended values (df_ap) after the condition is met, is this possible or should I try a completely new approach.

This is my current code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["C1", "C2", "C3"])
Var1 = input("Input ")

if Var1 == 1:
 df_ap = df.append({"C1": 100, "C2": 200, "C3":300}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
print(df_ap)
```

Output:

```
Input 1
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [C1, C2, C3]
Index: []
NameError: name 'df_ap' is not defined
```

Comment: "input" always returns a string which will never be equal to a number. Compare input with string or convert it to int.

Comment: @MichaelButscher. Great minds think alike :)

Comment: The issue isn't that the variable isn't "global", it's that the `if` body never executes.

Comment: At module level, outside of a function, all variables are "global" ("global" meaning variables at module level).

Comment: This exposes a second error - what do you want to happen when the `if` isn't true? And please, 4 spaces for indent, not 1. Scientists have proven we have enough spaces to last more than a hundred years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in order to make your condition working, you need to make sure your `input` has been converted into `int` before the `if` condition.
Since you using `df_ap` outside of the `if` condition, you have to define it outside the `if` as well, which is before the condition execution.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["C1", "C2", "C3"])
df_ap = pd.DataFrame()

Var1 = int(input("Input "))

if Var1 == 1:
 df_ap = df.append({"C1": 100, "C2": 200, "C3":300}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
print(df_ap)
```

Another way, you can simply reuse `df`, since it has been defined outside `if` condition:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["C1", "C2", "C3"])

Var1 = int(input("Input "))

if Var1 == 1:
 df = df.append({"C1": 100, "C2": 200, "C3":300}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Var_1` is a string not an integer so you have to cast as int or compare it with a string:

```
Var1 = int(input("Input "))

if Var1 == 1:
```

Or:

```
Var1 = input("Input ")

if Var1 == "1":
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the definition outside the if.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["C1", "C2", "C3"])
Var1 = input("Input ")

df_ap = None

if Var1 == 1:
    df_ap = df.append({"C1": 100, "C2": 200, "C3":300}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
print(df_ap)
```

Comment: This code will still fail when the `if` condition is not met. This code needs an error path.